# Is there a more advanced JSON parser than the one in vanila js?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a program that checks if JSON is correctly formatted but right now I can't get the errors right.

I use `JSON.parse()` to parse the json passed in, inside of a try/catch statement, then I take the error (if generated), and make a error message of my own. However, the error logged tells me that I have a error at position x, but I don't understand what the position is. I want to output an error that tells the user on which line and which column the error happened in the json. I have read that my current method cannot give me the line and column, but is there any way to do it, or is there an external library that can do this?

(Its just js, not ts or node)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the relevant parts of the code and the json structure (with any possible credentials redacted).

Comment: Why don't you understand what the position is? It's just a string index. If you want to know the line number, just count the number of newline characters before that index. And the column is the difference between that index and the index of the last newline before it.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @epascarello I am building my own. I am a hobbyist who builds  things for fun, and I am  making my validator with a feature that I see missing from other ones like it, actually, 2. #1: option to upload json or text files with json in them, #2: ability to download file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position is the index in the string at which the (first) unexpected character was found. For example

```
JSON.parse(`{"foo":bar`)
```

produces

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 7

because index 7 is

```
{"foo":bar
       ^
```

If that isn't enough for you, and you have newlines in the string as well, then it's trivial to identify the number of newlines before the error position - just slice the string from 0 to the position, then split by `\n` to find out the number of lines, and look at the number of characters in the last split string to find out the number of rows.

```js
const badJSON = `
{
  "foo"
  :
    'bar`;
try {
  JSON.parse(badJSON);
} catch(e) {
  const position = e.message.match(/\d+/)[0];
  const textToPosition = badJSON.slice(0, position);
  const splits = textToPosition.split('\n');
  const lines = splits.length;
  const columns = splits[lines - 1].length;
  console.log('Error at', lines, columns);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I need to wait 7 min to accept its the only reason im not doing it now

Comment: +1 This is almost comprehensive: the case it overlooks is that of when the invalid JSON is due to improper escaping of newlines in string values.